# Как передать переменную в шаблон регулярного выражения?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Нужно, сделать шаблон который обвернет пробелами число, переданное в `var a`. Что то типа такого:

```
 var a = 23;
 var cls = /\sa\s/;
```

Comment: `cls = " "+a+" "` - так не выходит?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var a = 23;
var re = new RegExp("\\s"+ a +"\\s");
```

Comment: re почему, то возвращает не /\s23\s/, а /s23s/. Дописал еще по одному обратному слэшу: var re = new RegExp("\\s" + a +"\\s"); и стало нормально

Comment: И правда, ошибся. Исправил.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = 23;
var cls = new RegExp('\s'+a+'\s');
```